# is there a way for an Admin to authenticate a user in the FE without the password of the user in Supabase?

Tags: authentication, supabase

The title is pretty explanative. Working with Supabase and, as an admin, I'd like to be able to get a session for a User that we can set on the FE and get logged in as the user.

Is it possible to get it via API?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [custom claims](https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-custom-claims).

Comment: thank you for your comments @Mansueli - although can't see how custom claims are related to the question.

Comment: Custom claims is probably one of the most scalable/performant ways of creating an admin panel/dashboard. 

Another way to simulate the log-in is `set role authenticated` and `set request.jwt.claim.sub to '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'` (UUID)

But that is in SQL, so you would have to use a `PostGres Library/driver` to run these in your admin page.